# Фиктивные Gps координаты

Tags: android

Как на андроид задать фиктивные координаты не включая функцию "разрешить фиктивное место положение" в опции разработчикам

Comment: По - моему никак, возможно я ошибаюсь. Однако все программы, которые  я использовал для этого, без этой опции не работали

Comment: У меня одного возникает вопрос "ЗАЧЕМ???". *разрешить фиктивное место положение* создана именно для того, чтобы *задать фиктивные координаты*. Зачем вы пытаетесь чесать левое ухо правой рукой при помощи синхрофазотрона, привязанного к правой руке потому, что без него не достает?

Answer (score 1):

На работе стоит такая же задача, и вроде бы как "рабочий" вариант мне даже [дали](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/1b725ffd19e546df4a31d31f39013d6d)
, но я пока что не проверял. Эта штука получает адреса ближайших вышек и в дальнейшем по этим адресам, используя какой-нибудь онлайн сервис координаты получить можно. Но! погрешность будет оооочень большая.